# How to check for the presence of a GPS sensor?

Tags: android, gps

I'm writing a method that will return true if there's a GPS sensor present and enabled, but returns false if it's absent or switched off. It's proving hard because...

```
hasSystemFeature("FEATURE_LOCATION_GPS")  // on PackageManager
```

Returns false, whether the device has a GPS or not. So even on a device that has one, and it's switched on, it still returns false. Seems completely wrong to me, but I can't see why.

```
isProviderEnabled("gps")   // on LocationManager
```

Returns true, even on a device I have here that has no GPS hardware at all. That also seems completely counter-intuitive.

I accept these results could be because I'm missing something, the SDK isn't intuitive, or perhaps even that the devices I'm testing with are behaving strangely.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should work. Is there any error messages in logcat when you make this call?

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
boolean hasGps = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LOCATION_GPS);
```

Comment: No error, but it returns true on a device that doesn't have a GPS at all (Advent Vega 10" non-Google-approved tablet). Perhaps the tablet is to blame and the OS is incorrectly set up on the device.

Comment: Well the device developer has to implement a PackageManager class since the SDK PackageManager is abstract. It wouldn't be the first time a device developer broke something.

Comment: I tested this on Kinde Fire (without GPS) and it works like a charm. (I guess it's not worth to support non-Google approved craps)

Answer (score 3):

In case when device does not have GPS hardware the following is true:

```
locationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) == null;
```

Where

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) AppCore.context().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

In my case the *hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LOCATION_GPS)* returns true even if device does not have GPS. So it's not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Your `hasSystemFeature()` probably always returns false because FEATURE_LOCATION_GPS is a reference to a constant, and not a string literal.  I believe the current string literal it points to is actually "android.hardware.location.gps".

I believe what you are looking for is something like this:

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
if(!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
    //Ask the user to enable GPS
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Location Manager");
    builder.setMessage("Would you like to enable GPS?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //Launch settings, allowing user to make a change
            Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //No location service, no Activity
            finish();
        }
    });
    builder.create().show();
}
```

I added the extra about the `AlertDialog` to point out that you can take the user to the Location settings page directly to have them enable GPS using the `Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS` Intent action.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, of course, the string needs to come via the static constant. I missed it as the constant is only in API8 and onwards and I'm targeting API5. But I added the constant manually as a string, and it works. I fully expect it may not work in all scenarios, but it's just a test to improve the UI where possible so not a bi deal if it fails for some, they won't know. Thanks.

Comment: I spoke too soon. hasSystemFeature("android.hardware.location.gps") returns true for both the device with GPS and the device without. How frustrating that something so simple is proving so hard. isProviderEnabled(Location.GPS_PROVIDER) is still returning true, even when the device has no GPS at all.

Comment: What are the two devices you are testing with?  Also, I thought I might point out that `LocationManager.getAllProviders()` will not have `LocationProvider.GPS_PROVIDER` in its returned list if it is not supported at all, which would be another way for you to check if GPS exists.