# Check if the GPS system is present on the android device , API levels 3 or 4

Tags: android, gps

I need to check if the GPS system is present on an android device.

I have seen the reply to the following question ,
[How to check for the presence of a GPS sensor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031895/how-to-check-for-the-presence-of-a-gps-sensor) ,but need to do it with an API level of 3 or 4.

The answer present on the link will work with a minimum of API Level of 5 for 
hasSystemFeature() and 8 for the PackageManager.FEATURE_LOCATION_GPS constant.

Thanks in advance.

Update :

Used the following code, implementing the solution from CommonsWare.

```
boolean gpsOnBoard;

LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
List<String> locProvs = locMan.getProviders(true);

// check if we have a valid list of providers
if (locProvs != null)
{
gpsOnBoard = false;

// check all providers 
    for (String locProvName:locProvs)
    {
    if (locProvName.equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
        {
    // we have GPS hw onboard
        gpsOnBoard = true;

    }
 }
```

Comment: Just an FYI, API levels 3 and 4 together make up less than 3% of the market.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29#Market_share

Comment: I am aware of that. Maybe I am being a bit pedantic, but would like to have the broadest compatibility possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Call [`getProviders()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getProviders%28boolean%29) on the `LocationManager` and see what providers are there.

Ideally, you do not hard-code GPS support in your app, as users might have that provider disabled, even if the hardware exists. Consider using `Criteria` and another flavor of [`getProviders()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getProviders%28android.location.Criteria,%20boolean%29) to allow Android to help you find an appropriate and available provider.

Comment: Will check getProviders. In this specific instance I want to be specific to GPS.