# Application crashes when I check if GPS sensor present in a sysyem?

Tags: android, gps

I followed answers given for [How to check for the presence of a GPS sensor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5031895/1713415)
 and did changes according but in all cases my app crashes.
I used

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
boolean hasGps = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LOCATION_GPS);
```

then again i modified my code and used

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
if (lm.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) == null) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                       "GPS sensor is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

but in both the cases my app crashes. Please tell me where m I going wrong?

Comment: Please add the logtrace and make sure you have the right permission in the Manifest.xml

Comment: I have added required permissions in the Manifest.xml and I m testing my app on Carbonn mobile (no gps hardware). but unfortunately I m not able to debug so i don't have logtrace.

Comment: @AndroidLover if you are unable to connect device with system, there are many **log collector** apps are available in the market. make use of them and update question with logcat. Without logcat stacktrace we are in a situation to search in the dark

Comment: @Sankar V as soon as i get logcat, ill update my question.

Comment: Another suggestion, check ALL objects to make sure they're not null before using them.  Even is something *can't possibly* be null, in this kind of situation it's better to check and make sure!

Comment: @Sankar V Thanks a lot man!! I have downloaded log collector app from https://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector and found the mistake made by me in a logtrace. I started location listener using gps, even when gps unavailable and because of that my app was getting crash..

Comment: @AndroidLover you can answer your question and accept it man. Kindly do that because it will be helpful to someone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found mistake in my code and did required changes.
Initially my code was

```
if((ProvidePreference.equalsIgnoreCase("BestAvailable")) {
//start both gps and network
     this.LocationMngr.requestLocationUpdates(
                   LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,captureFrequencey, 100, this); 
     this.LocationMngr.requestLocationUpdates(
                   LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,captureFrequencey, 0, this);
}
```

then i changed my code to

```
if((ProvidePreference.equalsIgnoreCase("BestAvailable") && 
             LocationMngr.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) != null)) {
//start both gps and network
     this.LocationMngr.requestLocationUpdates(
                 LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,captureFrequencey, 100, this); 
     this.LocationMngr.requestLocationUpdates(
                 LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,captureFrequencey, 0, this);
} else {
//start network 
     this.LocationMngr.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,captureFrequencey, 0, this);
}
```

NOTE- if provider is not available in a system then one should not attempt to start it.